# "Specified cast is not valid" casting the results of ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to code for a project, but the non-valid specific cast error keeps coming out. Can anyone help me as I am stumped. Thanks in advance.

```
Server Error in '/c#project' Application.

Specified cast is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Source Error: 


Line 39:         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.Char).Value = strProductId;
Line 40:         object oQty = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Line 41:         int intQuantityOnHand = (int)oQty;
Line 42:         mDB.Close();
Line 43:         int intBuyQuantity = int.Parse(ddlQty.Items[ddlQty.SelectedIndex].ToString());

Source File: c:\Users\jacob\Desktop\c#project\ProductDetails.aspx.cs    Line: 41 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   ProductDetails.btnBuy_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\jacob\Desktop\c#project\ProductDetails.aspx.cs:41
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Comment: What does cmd.ExecuteScalar() return?  Have you checked?

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with that.. try int oQty = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); then you dont need to box it to an integer

Comment: Try placing breakpoint at line 40 and examine what oQty is after ExecuteScalar. It could be that sql exception is thrown and oQty is null? Could you also show command text?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

Line 41: apparently `oQty` cannot be cast to `Int32`. Try

```
int intQuantityOnHand = Convert.ToInt32(oQty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is on line 41.  Put a breakpoint on line 41 and see what the value of oQty is.  It could be null.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a null check in case your result set is empty.

```
if(oQty!=null){
  int intQuantityOnHand = (int)oQty;
}
```

That, or default your value...

```
  int intQuantityOnHand = (oQty==null) ? 0 : (int)oQty;
```

Per MSDN, [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns

> [t]he first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.
>   Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
object oQty = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int? intQuantityOnHand = (oQty as int);
```

and then check `if(intQuantityOnHand !=null)`

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` returns [The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx). This could be anything; an integer, null, a string, varbinary. You have to examine the type of the first column of your query and assign to a variable of that type.

Also, why are you doing this:

```
int intBuyQuantity = int.Parse(ddlQty.Items[ddlQty.SelectedIndex].ToString());
```

You're converting something to a string, then the string to an integer. Why? Is it a string? Then that can throw an exception. Is it an integer? Then read it as an integer. Are you using `System.Data.SqlClient`? That contains methods like `GetInt32` which return data of the proper type; you don't need to cast, parse, or whatever.